# How do I ensure about non negative column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a table `Branch` with columns `branch_name` and `branch_city` character type, `assets` as integer type. `branch_name` is the primary key and I have to ensure that `assets` are non negative.

I tried like

```
CREATE TABLE Branch
(
    branch_name navarchar(100) primary key,
    branch_city nvarchar(100),
    assests int NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to **define** a datatype for your primary key, and you need to add a `CHECK` constraint to ensure `assets` is non-negative:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Branch
(
    branch_name NVARCHAR(100) primary key,
    branch_city nvarchar(100),
    assets int NOT NULL CHECK (assets >= 0)
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Alter your table creating a constraint to check the column

```
ALTER TABLE Branch ADD CONSTRAINT chkassets CHECK (assets > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
CREATE TABLE Branch (
    branch_name VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY
    ,branch_city NVARCHAR(100)
    ,assests INT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT ck_assets_positive CHECK (assests >= 0)
    )
```